# TS Error - Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnknownAction'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

My organization recently switched from using an older version of Redux to the newest version of Redux Toolkit, and I have been converting all of our actions and reducers to match the latest version of RTK. However, when I attempt to dispatch an async action from within another async action, I am receiving a TS error. Note that it is only when attempting to dispatch an async action (created with createAppAsyncThunk as advised in the docs), and not when dispatching an action created using createAction. Following is the received error:

`TS2345: Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction; extra?: unknown; rejectValue?: unknown; serializedErrorType?: unknown; pendingMeta?: unknown; fulfilledMeta?: unknown; rejectedMeta?: unknown; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnknownAction'.`

My question is, am I doing something wrong with my code that would cause me to be unable to perform this dispatch, or have I missed something bigger?

I have searched for this using multiple different params, and the closest responses I have come up with are from a couple of years ago (2020-2022), and relate to 'AnyAction', not 'UnknownAction' (I did see that in RTK v.2.0.0, AnyAction was deprecated in favor of UnknownAction). The most common responses I saw were either regarding the second param of createAsyncThunk (the thunkApi) or people not setting up their store / dispatch correctly, neither of which appears to be the case with our current setup.

As far as I can tell, according to the current RTK docs I have everything set up correctly. Aside from this issue with dispatching an async thunk from within another one not working, everything else is functioning perfectly as intended.

Below I have included generic code samples, omitting irrelevant details and code comments, aside from some clarification commentary. I didn't bother including the reducers here, as we are not having any issues with them and it didn't seem relevant to this issue. If more information is needed, I can provide it.

```
/**
 * Redux setup.
 */
export const store: Store = configureStore({
  reducer: combineReducers(getAllReducers()), // getAllReducers is defined elsewhere.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware(),
  devTools: import.meta.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export const createAppAsyncThunk = createAsyncThunk.withTypes<{
  state: RootState,
  dispatch: AppDispatch,
}>();


/**
 * Basic Toast Action called within one of the async thunks.
 */
type NotificationParams = {
  description: string;
  title?: string;
};
export const notifySuccess = createAction('NOTIFY_SUCCESS', (msg: NotificationParams) => {
  const props = {
    title: msg.title ?? '',
    description: msg.description,
  };
  // toast is imported, ToastMessageWrapper is a custom react component.
  toast.success(ToastMessageWrapper(props));
  return {
    payload: props,
  };
});


/**
 * Async Action 1. This is the common setup for our async actions.
 */
type FirstActionRequestParams = {
  paramA: SomeType;
  paramB: SomeOtherType;
};
export const firstAction = createAppAsyncThunk<
    SomeReturnType,
    FirstActionRequestParams
>('FIRST_ACTION', async (incomingParams, thunkApi) => {
  const { paramA, paramB } = incomingParams;

  try {
    // All of our graphql is extracted into a library that gets initialized on app load.
    if (LocalSDK.someService) {
      return await LocalSDK.someService.someMethod(paramA, paramB).
          then((resp: SomeReturnType) => {
            // some logic may or may not happen here.

            const msg: NotificationParams = {
              description: 'Some Description indicating success from a translation file.',
            };
            // Some actions are imported under aliases, such as systemActions.
            thunkApi.dispatch(systemActions.notifySuccess(msg)); // <- Works Perfectly.

            return resp;
          }).
          catch((err: SomeErrorType) => {
            // method defined elsewhere that dispatches toast notifications on failure.
            handleErrorType(err, 'FIRST_ACTION_FAILURE', thunkApi.dispatch);
            throw err;
          });
    } else {
      throw new Error('Error: SDK is not initialized.');
    }
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    // we have some custom error types. This is just indicating that we perform that process here.
    const returnData: SomeErrorType = error as SomeErrorType;
    return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(returnData);
  }
});


/**
 * Async Action 2. This action will attempt to call the first async action. There are occasions
 * where we know that immediately following one action, another needs to happen, or maybe happen
 * conditionally based on the response from this call, etc.
 */
type SecondActionRequestParams = {
  paramA: AnotherType;
  paramB: YetAnotherType;
};
export const secondAction = createAppAsyncThunk<
    AnotherReturnType,
    SecondActionRequestParams
>('SECOND_ACTION', async (incomingParams, thunkApi) => {
  const { paramA, paramB } = incomingParams;

  try {
    if (LocalSDK.anotherService) {
      return await LocalSDK.anotherService.someMethod(paramA, paramB).
          then((resp: AnotherReturnType) => {
            // some logic may or may not happen here, including type checks or whatever else.

            // This line fails with the listed error.
            thunkApi.dispatch(firstAction(resp.someParam, resp.someOtherParam));

            // Also tried the following as well, which never gets called. I didn't expect it
            //   to work, but figured it was worth a try.
            // firstAction(resp.someParam, resp.someOtherParam);

            return resp;
          }).
          catch((err: SomeErrorType) => {
            // method defined elsewhere that dispatches toast notifications on failure.
            handleErrorType(err, 'SECOND_ACTION_FAILURE', thunkApi.dispatch);
            throw err;
          });
    } else {
      throw new Error('Error: SDK is not initialized.');
    }
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    const returnData: SomeErrorType = error as SomeErrorType; // we have some custom error types.
    return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(returnData);
  }
});
```